# Black screen when booting normally

Tags: boot, grub2, 64-bit, 14.10, plymouth

### My system

- Laptop: Acer aspire 8930G
- OS: Freshly installed Ubuntu 14.10 (64 bit)
- Memory: 4 GB
- Processor: Intel Core 2 Duo CPU T9400 @ 2.53 GHz x 2
- Graphics: Nvidia GeForce 9700M GT / pre-installed open driver / Gallium 0.4 on NV96

[`lspci`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/9249039/)

### Problem

Ubuntu refuses to boot "normally". I always have to do a hard reset, before I am able to boot up without any problems. There also is no crash report or anything else, that wold indicate that there was a previous failed boot attempt, that was aborted by me pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>.

This problem wasn't caused by an update. It exists since installation. I've reinstalled Ubuntu twice and always encounter the described problem. I've checked the install medium.

The problem also persists when normally rebooting Ubuntu.

I have LUKS encryption enabled.

#### Normal boot attempt

When I try to boot Ubuntu (normally), the following happens:

1. BIOS screen (Acer logo). Fan starts spinning at a normal rate.
2. Black screen for about a quarter of a second.
3. Purple screen for about two seconds.
4. Black screen. The screen isn't only blank, it is completely turned off, including the backlight. The fan stops spinning. It's as if the laptop is dead.
5. I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> and the laptop reboots after a few seconds.

**Edit:**

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, LUKS flashes up for a split second, before I get to the console. Pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> then actually brings me back to the LUKS prompt and I am able to enter my password.

It seems like Ubuntu just doesn't automatically switch into plymouth and I have to do it manually. What is the root of this problem and why doesn't it happen when booting after a hard reset?

#### Reboot after hard reset

The weird thing is, after this "hard reset", the laptop boots up just fine:

1. BIOS screen (Acer logo). Fan starts spinning at a normal rate.
2. Black screen for about a quarter of a second.
3. The GRUB menu appears:

   - Ubuntu *(selected)*
   - Advanced options for Ubuntu
   - Memory test (memtest86+)
   - Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)
4. I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and Ubuntu boots just fine, as if nothing happened.
5. plymouth asks for my password LUKS password.
6. I enter it and the boot continues without further problems.

Comment: Have you tried the solutions given here? https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/plymouth/+bug/1359689

Comment: I already reinstalled Ubuntu, which "fixed" the problem. Thank you nevertheless. I am sure, a lot of Google users will be thankful. :)

Answer (score 0):

I use this solution:

In `/boot/grub/grub.conf` find menu entry of Ubuntu and remove this two lines:

```
load_video
gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
```

Then save the file and reboot.
It was helpful for me.